# InstallShield LE isn't installing ReportViewer 2010 from my VS 2010 C# Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installshield-le

InstallShield LE isn't installing ReportViewer 2010 from my VS 2010 C# Project. I have ReportViewer 2010 selected as a requirement but it's not adding the files I need. Its also not adding the SQL CE 3.5 run-time either. I can get the "Visual Studio Installer" to add both but I understand MS is going to be removing this from future versions of VS. I'd like to start using what they want to go forward with, but it seems to be less capable.

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: Are you launching the installation by double clicking the EXE bootstrapper? If so, what is the exact behavior you are encountering?

Comment: Yes. The ReportViewer simply isn't being installed. So when I try to run a report an exception is thrown saying I'm missing one of it's DLL's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK found the answer. The walk-thru they give doesn't give the option to specify whether or not prerequisites should be installed. Rather, in the Solution Explorer under the name of the setup project is a section called "2 Specify Application Data" and under it, is a section called "redistributables". This was the section I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even know you could do this but it definitely helped me resolve a few issues!